# Swift ui macos menu bar list transparent

Tags: swift, list, macos, swiftui, menubar

[image]

I have the following list appearing in the menu bar, but the list appears with a background, I would like it to be seen with a transparent background.

Code:

```
    List(fetch.todos) { todo in
        VStack(alignment: .leading, spacing: 0) {
            Text(todo.title)
            Text("\(todo.completed.description)")
                .font(.system(size: 11))
                .foregroundColor(Color.gray)
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add the `.listStyle(SidebarListStyle())` modifier to your `List` view to make it match the transparency of the system.

Comment: I did as you indicated, I don't know what happens but everything breaks, crashes.

Comment: It's makes the background transparent, but there are few side effects: text becomes smaller and the list stops supporting linebreaks.